# plotly::add_annotations() cannot handle factor variables (?)

Tags: r, plotly

when adding text to cells of a heatmap produced with plotly, I use `add_annotiations()`,
like this:

```
Grid <- expand.grid(x=1:3,y=4:6)
Grid <- cbind(Grid, z=rnorm(9))
plot_ly(
  data=Grid,
  x=~x, y=~y, z=~z,
  type='heatmap') %>%
  add_annotations(text = letters[1:9], showarrow = FALSE)
```

But now I have a dataset where `x` and `y` are factors,
so for the toy example above let's define factor variables:

If I now execute the very same code,
annotations no longer align.

```
Grid$xFac <- as.character(Grid$x)
Grid$yFac <- as.factor(Grid$y)

plot_ly(
  data=Grid,
  x=~xFac, y=~yFac, z=~z,
  type='heatmap') %>%
  add_annotations(
    text = letters[1:9], showarrow = FALSE)
```

How do I match annotations to respective cells whilst using factor variables for `x` or `y` ?

EDIT:
@Max Teflon thanks for having a look at my code,
I tried on a different operating system, but the issue persists,
Now I'm really curious wheter other people can reproduce (or even explain) the issue.

For me, the latter plot still looks like this, unfortunately:

[image: add_annotations_factor]

The OS I tried so far are

```r
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.9.3  ggplot2_3.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] statmod_1.4.35    tidyselect_1.1.0  xfun_0.20         purrr_0.3.4      
 [5] splines_4.0.4     lattice_0.20-41   colorspace_2.0-0  vctrs_0.3.6      
 [9] generics_0.1.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1 viridisLite_0.3.0 yaml_2.2.1       
[13] rlang_0.4.10      nloptr_1.2.2.2    pillar_1.4.7      glue_1.4.2       
[17] withr_2.4.0       foreach_1.5.1     lifecycle_0.2.0   munsell_0.5.0    
[21] gtable_0.3.0      htmlwidgets_1.5.3 codetools_0.2-18  evaluate_0.14    
[25] knitr_1.30        crosstalk_1.1.1   Rcpp_1.0.6        scales_1.1.1     
[29] DHARMa_0.3.3.0    jsonlite_1.7.2    farver_2.0.3      lme4_1.1-26      
[33] packrat_0.5.0     digest_0.6.27     dplyr_1.0.2       grid_4.0.4       
[37] tools_4.0.4       magrittr_2.0.1    lazyeval_0.2.2    tibble_3.0.6     
[41] crayon_1.3.4      tidyr_1.1.2       pkgconfig_2.0.3   MASS_7.3-53      
[45] ellipsis_0.3.1    Matrix_1.2-18     data.table_1.13.6 minqa_1.2.4      
[49] rmarkdown_2.6     httr_1.4.2        rstudioapi_0.13   iterators_1.0.13 
[53] R6_2.5.0          boot_1.3-26       nlme_3.1-151      compiler_4.0.4
```

and

```r
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 20

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets
[6] methods   base

other attached packages:
  [1] plotly_4.9.3  ggplot2_3.3.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        pillar_1.5.0      compiler_4.0.4
[4] tools_4.0.4       digest_0.6.27     jsonlite_1.7.2
[7] lifecycle_1.0.0   tibble_3.1.0      gtable_0.3.0
[10] lattice_0.20-41   viridisLite_0.3.0 pkgconfig_2.0.3
[13] rlang_0.4.10      Matrix_1.3-2      crosstalk_1.1.1
[16] yaml_2.2.1        xfun_0.21         withr_2.4.1
[19] dplyr_1.0.4       httr_1.4.2        generics_0.1.0
[22] vctrs_0.3.6       htmlwidgets_1.5.3 grid_4.0.4
[25] tidyselect_1.1.0  glue_1.4.2        data.table_1.14.0
[28] R6_2.5.0          fansi_0.4.2       farver_2.0.3
[31] purrr_0.3.4       tidyr_1.1.2       magrittr_2.0.1
[34] scales_1.1.1      ellipsis_0.3.1    htmltools_0.5.1.1
[37] splines_4.0.4     colorspace_2.0-0  utf8_1.1.4
[40] tinytex_0.29      lazyeval_0.2.2    munsell_0.5.0
[43] crayon_1.4.1
```

Comment: Strange, they do align when I run your code on my machine...

Comment: thanks! could you tell what OS you're working on? I added my session info above.

Comment: My system info:
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Manjaro Linux

And I'm running plotly_4.9.2.1

Comment: Wow, thanks again, with version 4.9.2.1 the text is nicely aliged when i run the code above. .. .